# Unify the size of two tables

Tags: tables, boxes

How can I unify the table size and the font size for these two tables

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
%   Table 1
\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Day}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Summary}}                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
\textbf{Monday}                     & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A clear day with lots of sunshine. \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Tuesday}                   & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cloudy with rain, across many\\ northern regions, clear spells,across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far\\ northwest.\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

%   Table 2
\begin{table}[h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Min Temp}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Max Temp}} \\ \hline
\textbf{11C}                            & \textbf{22C}                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
%   Table 1
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 p{\dimexpr0.8\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\hline
\textbf{Day} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Summary}}                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
\textbf{Monday}                    & \textbf{A clear day with lots of sunshine.} \\ \hline
\textbf{Tuesday}                   & \textbf{Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions, clear spells,across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest.} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%   Table 2
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
\hline
\textbf{Min Temp}                       & \textbf{Max Temp} \\ \hline
\textbf{11C}                            & \textbf{22C}                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you load the [tabularx](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package, which provides the `tabularx` environment and a column type named `X`, LaTeX will perform all required column width calculations for you automatically.

Line breaks are inserted automatically, as needed, in the material that's in a column of type `X` (or in a column of a type that's based on `X` -- as in the first table below).

What's left for you is to specify the desired *overall width* of the table, say, `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
%% create two additional column types that are based on the 'X' type
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % for ragged-right material
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}   % for centered material

\begin{document}
%   Table 1
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|L|}
\hline
\textbf{Day} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Summary}}\\ 
\hline
\textbf{Monday} & 
\textbf{A clear day with lots of sunshine.}\\ 
\hline
\textbf{Tuesday} & 
\textbf{Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions, clear spells,across most of 
    Scotland and Northern Ireland, but rain reaching the far northwest.} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

%   Table 2
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|C|}
\hline
\textbf{Min Temp} & \textbf{Max Temp} \\ 
\hline 
\textbf{11C} & \textbf{22C} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```